# JBoss: NoClassDefFoundError RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl

Tags: spring, jboss, jaxb, cxf

I am getting below error, even though com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl class is present in jaxb-impl-2.2.11 jar.

Error Stacktrace:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:63) [jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
```

The error is coming on starting JBoss 7 server. Application has Spring 4.3.2 and cxf 3.1.7 dependencies.

Please find below relevant jars in the classpath:

```
<resource-root path="cxf-bundle-compatible-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-core-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-bindings-corba-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-databinding-aegis-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-databinding-xmlbeans-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-javascript-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-management-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-rs-service-description-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-transports-jms-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-transports-local-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-common-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-corba-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-java2ws-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-misctools-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-validator-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-wadlto-jaxrs-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-wsdlto-core-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-javascript-3.1.7.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws-3.1.7.jar"/>


<resource-root path="javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar"/>
<resource-root path="javax.xml.soap-api-1.3.5.jar"/>
<resource-root path="jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar"/>
<resource-root path="jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar"/>
<resource-root path="jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar"/>
<resource-root path="jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar"/>
<resource-root path="jaxws-api-2.2.11.jar"/>

<resource-root path="jersey-bundle-1.19.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="jettison-1.2.jar"/>

<resource-root path="spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
<resource-root path="spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
<resource-root path="spring-context-support-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
<resource-root path="spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
<resource-root path="spring-expression-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>

<resource-root path="stax2-api-3.1.4.jar"/>
<resource-root path="wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar"/>
<resource-root path="xalan-2.7.0.jar"/>
<resource-root path="xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="xml-resolver-1.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
<resource-root path="xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar"/>
<resource-root path="xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar"/>
<resource-root path="xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar"/>
<resource-root path="xstream-1.4.7.jar"/>
```

Relevant pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle-compatible</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: It could be possible due to jaxb version conflicts. I think `jersey-bundle` already ships with `jaxb impl`. Can you try remove `jaxb-impl jar` and check ?

Comment: I am not adding jaxb-impl explicitly, It is coming transitively from cxf-bundle-compatible 3.1.7 dependency.

Comment: if you using maven, `exclude` jaxb-impl dependency from cxf-bundle.

Comment: Getting ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory on excluding jaxb-impl.

Comment: pls post pom.xml on what runtime dependencies you are including exactly.

Comment: added pom dependencies in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122813/discussion-between-ulab-and-vikas-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Error gone after adding below dependencies in module.xml file:

```
<module name="javax.jws.api" />
<module name="javaee.api" />
<module name="javax.annotation.api" />
```